# Full screen chart without a scroll slider in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

How to make a full-width chart with a fixed chart height with no empty space on the sides and no horizontal scroll slider?

I have not been able to achieve this with `autosize` and `autorange`.

```
var layout = {
  autosize: true,
  height: 500,
  showlegend: false,
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: [dates[0], dates[dates.length - 1]]
  }
}
```

[image]